# VBA Error Handling: Catch and Re-throw Not Propagating

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am working on a fairly large VBA application and want to ensure that I robustly deal with errors.

In my calling sub/function I want to catch the error and pass it to a global error handler.

My solution is based on:
[Dymeng - Rethrow Errors](https://dymeng.com/rethrowing-vba-errors/)
and
[ExcelMacroMastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#Expected_Versus_Unexpected_Errors)

The global error handler builds the call stack and then re-raises the error.

The problem I am experiencing is that the re-raising the error on the global error handler does not return the program flow back to the calling context and a VBA Error modal is displayed instead.

In the example below the SQL query attempts to insert a row with a duplicate index.  This triggers a Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error.

Global Error Handler (in module UTIL_ErrorHandler):

```
    Sub HandleError (ByVal p_Error As DO_Error)
        ' Manipulate the error data
        '...
        'Clear the error and re-raise
        'REMOVED in response to Wayne's answer: On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Raise p_Error.Number, p_Error.Source, p_Error.Description
    End Sub
```

Calling Code (in Class UTIL_Database)

```
    Public Function Query (ByVal p_querySQL AS String) As ADODB.RecordSet
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
      'connection code...
      'query code...
    ExitProc:
      Exit Function
    ErrHandler:
      Dim myError as New DO_Error
      myError.Construct(Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Erl, 
                          "UTIL_Database.Query")
      UTIL_ErrorHandler.HandleError myError
      Resume ExitProc
      Resume
    End Function
```

When debugging the debugger halts on Err.Raise

Why is control not returned to the Query function and how can I resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: You have 'On Error GoTo 0' which means 'I will handle this myself'. So when you 'Raise' the error it stops on that line. We did similar code where every Sub/Function had error traps and we captured the error information to a database table for analysis. However, we just passed the info to a Function whereas you 'Raise' the error a second time.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for the quick response.  I've taken out the 'On Error GoTo 0' and the outcome remains the same. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my noob idiocy!

I had  Error Trapping set to **Break in Class Module**.  Once I changed this to **Break on Unhanded Errors** the situation resolved.